# How to have a 2D icon (imported image) as a 3D point in a table of points?

Tags: plotting, graphics, list-manipulation, marker

I'm following the tutorial on `RandomPoint` seen here:

```
bounds = {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 1}};

\[ScriptCapitalR] = Cuboid @@ Transpose[bounds];

rp = RandomPoint[\[ScriptCapitalR], 634];

rv = RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[bounds], 634];

Table[Graphics3D[{PointSize[Tiny], Point[p]},
Boxed -> False], {p, {rp, rv}}]
```

However, I want the points to be either of two images in a list, say,

```
im1 = Import["https://www.theplaceigotmyimagefrom.com/file1.png"]

im2 = Import["https://www.theplaceigotmyimagefrom.com/file2.png"]

L=List[im1]

L=Append[L,im2]
```

And then I'd use something like `PlotMarkers->RandomChoice[L]` for the points...

Comment: Look up `Inset[]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. First, let us import 3 standard images. You will then import your own:

```
lst = Image[Import[#],ImageSize -> {20, 20}] & /@ {"ExampleData/rose.gif", "ExampleData/spikey.tiff","ExampleData/girlcloseup.jpg"}
```

[image]

Then let us plot three random points. Take care that to apply markers it should be a nested, rather than a plain list:

```
ListPlot[Table[RandomInteger[{1, 9}, {1, 2}], {3}], PlotMarkers -> lst]
```

[image]

Another way is to use the `Epilog->Inset` construct. To do this let us plot any graphics as a background, say a white rectangle. On this background, we can make the insets. First let us form a list of the images with their coordinates:

```
lst1 = Transpose[{lst, RandomInteger[{0, 10}, {3, 2}]}]
```

Now we can plot

```
Graphics[{White, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {10, 10}]}, 
 Epilog -> (Inset[#[[1]], #[[2]]] & /@ lst1)]
```

[image]

Have fun!